# Gostaria de saber todas as combinações de 5 números entre 0 e 100 que somados sejam 100

Tags: python

Boa noite,

Eu preciso achar todas as combinações de 5 números naturais, entre 0 e 100 (podendo ser 0,0,0,0,100 (pode repetir)) que somados sejam igual a 100, eu adaptei o código abaixo para fazer isso, mas por algum motivo o código cai em um loop.

Eu sei que essa combinações de 5 números naturais (podendo repetir) para os números entre 0 e 100 geram 10.510.100.501 possibilidades, mas eu só preciso das combinações que somando os valores cheguem a 100.

```
from itertools import combinations
lis = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,16,17,17,17,17,17,18,18,18,18,18,19,19,19,19,19,20,20,20,20,20,21,21,21,21,21,22,22,22,22,22,23,23,23,23,23,24,24,24,24,24,25,25,25,25,25,26,26,26,26,26,27,27,27,27,27,28,28,28,28,28,29,29,29,29,29,30,30,30,30,30,31,31,31,31,31,32,32,32,32,32,33,33,33,33,33,34,34,34,34,34,35,35,35,35,35,36,36,36,36,36,37,37,37,37,37,38,38,38,38,38,39,39,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,42,43,43,43,43,43,44,44,44,44,44,45,45,45,45,45,46,46,46,46,46,47,47,47,47,47,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,50,50,50,50,50,51,51,51,51,51,52,52,52,52,52,53,53,53,53,53,54,54,54,54,54,55,55,55,55,55,56,56,56,56,56,57,57,57,57,57,58,58,58,58,58,59,59,59,59,59,60,60,60,60,60,61,61,61,61,61,62,62,62,62,62,63,63,63,63,63,64,64,64,64,64,65,65,65,65,65,66,66,66,66,66,67,67,67,67,67,68,68,68,68,68,69,69,69,69,69,70,70,70,70,70,71,71,71,71,71,72,72,72,72,72,73,73,73,73,73,74,74,74,74,74,75,75,75,75,75,76,76,76,76,76,77,77,77,77,77,78,78,78,78,78,79,79,79,79,79,80,80,80,80,80,81,81,81,81,81,82,82,82,82,82,83,83,83,83,83,84,84,84,84,84,85,85,85,85,85,86,86,86,86,86,87,87,87,87,87,88,88,88,88,88,89,89,89,89,89,90,90,90,90,90,91,91,91,91,91,92,92,92,92,92,93,93,93,93,93,94,94,94,94,94,95,95,95,95,95,96,96,96,96,96,97,97,97,97,97,98,98,98,98,98,99,99,99,99,99,100,100,100,100,100]

for i in (4, len(lis)):
    for comb in combinations(lis, i):
       if sum(comb) == 100:
           print (comb,'= 100')
```

Muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Não vejo outra opção senão testar as "10.510.100.501 possibilidades"(informação do autor) de permutas. Fiz esse exemplo [aqui](https://repl.it/repls/OpaqueLemonchiffonBackup) usando uma lista simplificada porém se fizer usando sua lista vai demandar muita memória e tempo de processamento.

Comment: @AugustoVasques A equação geratriz parece ser muito simples: Todos os números de 0 a 100 repetidos 5 vezes cada.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Depois que escrevi que vi.

Answer (score 2):

1. Percorra `a` de `0` até `100`.
2. Percorra `b` de `0` até `100 - a`.
3. Percorra `c` de `0` até `100 - a - b`.
4. Percorra `d` de `0` até `100 - a - b - c`.
5. `e = 100 - a - b - c - d`.

Comment: Sim, isso na teoria está correto, mas a minha dúvida é como eu poderia programar um código em python para fazer isso.

Answer (score -1):

Eu achei esse código, que apresenta todas as combinações possíveis para 0 a 100 nas 5 "casas", mas não consegui fazer com que ele liste somente os valores que somados sejam 100.

```
import itertools

for i in intertools.product [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100],repeat=5):

print(i)
```

Comment: É só usar o [código que já te passaram em outro comentário](https://repl.it/repls/OpaqueLemonchiffonBackup) (basicamente é só trocar a lista) - se bem que, vem vez de colocar essa lista com todos os números, você pode simplesmente usar `range(101)`, que já gera a sequência de todos os números entre 0 e 100

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta com esta informação, já que não é uma resposta...